# Elementary Tweaks - How can I Toggle "Prefer Dark Theme" via Terminal?

Tags: settings, pantheon-terminal, themes, command-line, programming

I just installed the elementary-tweaks package on Freya, and was wondering if there was a way to control the **Prefer Dark Theme** option programmatically with a script, or directly via the terminal. I am quite new to elementary OS and Linux in general so I don't really have much experience with such tasks. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

I am referring to this **Prefer Dark Theme** toggle option:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an command for this, but you can edit a file.
Create/edit the following file:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

And change it to this:

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```